# checking a Numpy 3d array against a geodataframe

Tags: python, numpy, geopandas

I am working with numpy array where I have certain groundwaterlevels for different coordinates(interpolated). I would like to nullify points on my array that are not with in a geodataframe I am checking against. I have a working code but the number of loops is quite large. If anyone can suggest a better way? my current code is as follows:

```
        x = np.array(SpatialTable['x'])
        y = np.array(SpatialTable['y'])
        z = np.array(SpatialTable['Difference']) 
        #identify the extreme points of the aquifer system for which data is available
        lon_min = min(x)
        lat_min = min(y)
        lon_max = max(x)
        lat_max = max(y)
        #create grid points of defined spacing for interpolation, spacing in x and y=150
        numcols, numrows = int((lon_max-lon_min)/150), int((lat_max-lat_min)/150)
        xi = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, numcols)
        yi = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, numrows)
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)  
        #interpolate the data available for all defined grid points
        zi = griddata((x,y),z,(xx,yy),method='cubic')  
        for i in range(numcols):
            for j in range(numrows):
                if (np.isnan(zi[j][i])==False):
                    if (Point(xi[i],yi[j]).within(shape['geometry'][0]) or \Point(xi[i],yi[j]).within(shape['geometry'][1]) or Point(xi[i],yi[j]).within(shape['geometry'][2]) or \`enter code here`Point(xi[i],yi[j]).within(shape['geometry'][3])):
                        pass
                    else:
                        zi[j][i]=np.nan
```

Comment: Could you try to provide a small, reproducible example?

Comment: So what i want to do is check if the points in a numpy mesh are inside a polygon. there is solution provided in the link below but i have a mesh with 200000 points so looping through each point makes the run time quite long. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do it.                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283127/removing-numpy-meshgrid-points-outside-of-a-shapely-polygon